# MATLAB graph to adjacency matrix?

Tags: matlab, matrix, graph

I can create a graph using the matlab functions but I need to create an adjacency matrix from the graph now.

Here is how I created the graph:

```
s = roadmap.edges(:,1);  % vector [1, 2, 3, 4, ...]
t = roadmap.edges(:,2);  % vector [1, 2, 3, 4, ...]
weights = roadmap.edge_lengths';  % vector [1, 2, 3, 4, ...]
G = graph(s, t, weights);
```

I need to create a adjacency matrix from this data and I want it to look like this:

```
G = [0 3 9 0 0 0 0;
     0 0 0 7 1 0 0;
     0 2 0 7 0 0 0;
     0 0 0 0 0 2 8;
     0 0 4 5 0 9 0;
     0 0 0 0 0 0 4;
     0 0 0 0 0 0 0;
     ];
```

Comment: Does the confusingly named [`adjacency`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/graph.adjacency.html) not suffice?

Comment: I want a 2D vector. adjacency function actually makes a new structure.

Comment: No it doesn't, it [returns](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/graph.adjacency.html#buofhp9-5) a [sparse matrix](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html). You convert a sparse matrix to a full matrix using [`full`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/full.html). I have no idea what a 2D vector is.

Comment: Thanks, I got what I was looking for.